# Replacing "bubbling" hardwood floor with carpet

Tags: concrete, flooring, hardwood-floor, carpet

My house has solid stone walls and it's in a humid climate (Wales, UK). When I moved in the ground floor living room floor was floating hardwood on top of a layer of fibreboard on top of a concrete slab.

Every summer when the weather gets warm, the hardwood floor expands and "bubbles up" in the middle. It's a bit like walking on a water bed. It stays like that for the duration of the summer and then goes flat again in the autumn. Each year I would cut a few millimetres out from the perimeter of the floor where it meets the wall, which helped, but the next year it would expand again, seemingly without limit!

Now I've admitted defeat and have pulled the hardwood floor up, with a view to replacing it with underlay and carpet. However, I would like to diagnose the problem because if it's a damp issue I presume it could also affect my carpet.

The concrete floor appears to have a vapour barrier installed (I can see the edges of it poking out of the concrete). There are no signs of moisture having gathered on the concrete floor or any salt residue from previous moisture - it's clean.

Being an old stone house in a wet country, there *are* places where moisture could get in. However, the bubbling up of the floor did not coincide with wet weather.

Could the issue be moisture from the air condensing on the concrete slab at certain times of the year and being absorbed by the wooden floor? If so, would I expect my carpet also to get damp?

The carpet fitter can supply underlay with a vapour barrier. However, I assume this is only useful if the issue is moisture rising through the concrete rather than condensing from the air in the room?

My hope is that any condensation on the concrete will evaporate more easily through carpet and therefore the problem won't exhibit itself to the same extent. Is this reasonable?

Comment: can you live w/o carpet until the season the old problems would present themselves? That's one sure-fire way to tell. I would suspect that there wouldn't be much condensation on a slab under dense fibre and hardwood as the materials both wick and stop most airflow. You could test that with a frozen brick covered with said material; wait an hour, peel back cover and look for condensation.